# Expanding var in var in Windows CMD

Tags: cmd

I have smth like `%SystemRoot%\blahblahblah` in a variable (for example, `variable a`). 
But `echo !a!` will return `%SystemRoot%\blahblahblah` (without expanding `%SystemRoot%`). How can I expand it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a trick of calling a subroutine that will cause the variable to be expanded twice:

```
@Echo Off
set a=%%SystemRoot%%\blahblahblah
call :reparse set b=%a%

echo value of a: %a%
echo value of b: %b%

goto :EOF

:reparse
%*
goto :EOF
```

The `:reparse` subroutine just executes all its parameters. The first expansion occurs when executing the call and the second occurs when %* is interpreted as `set b=%SystemRoot%\blahblahblah`.